# Do all Federation starships have stasis chambers for the entire crew?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the Voyager episode [One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_%28Star_Trek:_Voyager%29) the entire crew (minus Seven and the doctor) are put into stasis chambers while they fly through a nebula that's teeming with subnucleonic radiation.

Do all Federation starships have stasis chambers for the entire crew?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can tell you for a fact that as of the 4th season of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, neither the series bible (the *Writer's Guide*) nor the *Writer's Technical Guide* mentioned a single thing about any kind of stasis chambers on the *Enterprise*.

In other words, they were added in sometime after that, when the plot needed it, but they were not conceived as a part of the ships when the newer Trek started airing.

Answer (score 8):

The Memory Alpha page about [stasis chambers](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Stasis_unit) says the following:

> Stasis units have become standard equipment on Starfleet vessels,
>   including the Galaxy-class and Defiant-class starships.

However, it seems like hauling around one chamber for *every* crew member could take up quite a lot of storage space, particularly on [*Galaxy*-class ships](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Galaxy_class) with crew complements that can exceed 1,000. Conceivably they could carry a minimum number and then replicate the parts and construct additional units as needed.

Comment: I would think that regardless of the crew compliment it would take a significant amount of space for that many stasis chambers. On a ship like the _Defiant_ it would make sense to integrate the stasis chambers into the individual bunks, otherwise the volume wasted would be depressingly limiting. For a ship like the _Enterprise-D_ it would require a significant volume, but given how much space is wasted, it isn't incomprehensible that they could find the space.

Comment: +1 @erdiede given the sizes of the cargo holds and shuttle bays on a Galaxy class ship it should be possible to efficiently stack and arrange the stasis pods on said class of ship in the availble open space throughout the ship.

Comment: @Xantec not to rag on the writers, but I always thought that a stasis module with battery backup for every person assigned to a set of quarters would simplify SOOO many of their problems. It would also eliminate half of their scripts, but que sera sera.